# Restoring SQL Server DB trans log files error

Tags: sql-server, corruption, restore, transaction-log

I am getting error when restoring DB trans log files.
Running

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = xxxxxx
```

is returning a message

> The backup set on file 1 is valid

However when running

```
RESTORE LOG [db_name] FROM DISK = xxxxxx
```

I get error

> The log scan number (yyyyyyyyyyyy) passed to log scan in database '[db_name]' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication.
> Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.
> RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

There is a replication setup on the DB that I am applying the logs backup file. Does it mean that the trans log backup is corrupted or there is something with the replication.

Why does the `Verifyonly` check return that the file is valid?

Comment: Just curious and partly guessing, is it master database?

Comment: no it is not a master DB

Comment: Do you have the option to do it through GUI? When I restore translogs (often due to the need to go back in time, before a mistake was done), I preferr to use SMSS GUI.

Comment: I get this same error when trying to apply the logs in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

first question

error message suggest 2 causes either database corruption, have you run dbcc checkdb ? or that the log file does not match the data file (transaction log backup from wrong db?).

From what I can see this error occurred during a transaction log restore not during replication so you can ignore that part of the error message.

second question

verifyonly is checking that the backup file is readable and complete - it is not checking the entire logic as clearly stated in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15